# MS Access Update Table with data being aggregated in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have a table in Access 2010, that I am trying to update the TotalDiary column with data from a query.

```
DiaryDt | EEID | EEName | EESpvrsID | OutOfDiary | TotalDiary
1/2/14  | 123  | phis   | text      |  5         |
```

I'm sure this is simplier than I am making it out to be, but I cannot get it to work.  My query below is the data that needs updated into the TotalDiary column...

```
    SELECT
    a.TotalDiary, b.EEID

   FROM ((

SELECT 
e.EEID, COUNT(c.CaseID) as TotalDiary
FROM ((dbo_Case c
LEFT JOIN dbo_Employee e ON e.EEID = c.CaseEEID)
LEFT JOIN Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl a ON a.EEID = e.EEID)
WHERE c.CaseStatus <> 6
AND a.DiaryDt = Date()
GROUP BY e.EEID
) a
LEFT JOIN Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl b ON b.EEID = a.EEID)

WHERE b.DiaryDt = Date()
```

I need for the Update Query to Set TotalDiary = a.TotalDiary Where b.EEID = TableToUpdate.EEID

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is dbo_Employee even in this query?  What purpose does it serve if you're not using anything from it and Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl has an EEID field?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't need to be in there, but taking that out doesn't really impact the end result I'm looking for.

Comment: Probably not, but it adds a level of complexity to the SQL string.  And, given that none of us but you knows the fields in those tables, it also adds a level of confusion.  I've never written a SQL string with "FROM ((" in it, and you've got 2 of them in one statement.  Since I don't know your table structures, all I can do is suggest you build this string from the inside out.  Start with the GROUP BY query that will get you the Count you need, and then build the other Join around it.  Also, you shouldn't have to filter by DiaryDt twice.